# Simple column change query doesn' work in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7

I have an update query created by MySQL Workbench 8 and it looks as follows:

```sql
-- MySQL Workbench Synchronization
-- Generated: 2019-12-16 00:30
-- Model: New Model
-- Version: 1.0
-- Project: Name of the project
-- Author: user0

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

ALTER TABLE `best_bpgallery`.`k96qw_bpgallery_images` 
CHANGE COLUMN `language` `language` NCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '*' ;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

It looks perfectly fine for me, but when I run it fails:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '*'' at line 2
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `best_bpgallery`.`k96qw_bpgallery_images` 
        CHANGE COLUMN `language` `language` NCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '*' 

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I even compared the query to [ALTER TABLE documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) and it looks fine for me. So what's going on? What am I missing?

Comment: NCHAR? You sure it is all about MySQL?

Comment: @fifonik Yes, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-national.html and this is the query build by MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Hm. Never seen it. Are you sure that you can specify CHARSET/COLLATE on the data type?

Comment: Note that on this page NCHAR doesn't have an explicit character set which your `ALTER TABLE` statement does have. The definition seems to include 'use some predefined character set' so making it optional seem counter to the purpose.

Comment: The problem is definitely NCHAR. I can use NCHAR without CHARACTER SET and COLLATE but when I add anything else it fails. @danblack You're right. As it is written in here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-national.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change nchar to varchar for example.

```
ALTER TABLE `best_bpgallery`.`k96qw_bpgallery_images` 
CHANGE COLUMN `language` `language` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '*' ;
```

nchar doesn't support charecter set

Comment: Yea, i see it now in the docs. @danblack comment pointed me to the right direction. But still thanks.